# Vue JS - button wrapper - can inherit events?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I'm working with `Vuetify` and I want to create my own `submit`,`cancel` etc. buttons so the website is homogenous.

So I'm going to define my button:

```
 Vue.component('pt-submit', {
        data: function () {
            return {
            }
        },
        template: '<v-btn color="success">Submit</v-btn>'
    });
```

But I would like to inherit/user `events` from `v-btn` like `@click`. How can I do that so I can use `pt-submit` the same way as `<v-btn>` without having to define color,classes etc?

Comment: Any updates on this question? Does my answer helps you?

Comment: @Raffobaffo yes, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Emit them when the v-btn emits them:

```
template: '<v-btn color="success" @click="$emit('click')">Submit</v-btn>'
```